# Blender's video output is different than the preview

Tags: video, audio

I made a short video with some recorded gameplay (from a rather low-fps game). The recorded clips have a varying framerate between 20-35 fps. I set Blender to render the clips in 60 fps, turned on AV-Sync, then added some audio and a scene "alpha-over" layer and it all looked great in the preview and rendered images.

But after I rendered the full video (with H264, encoding format also H264, and again in 60 fps), the video became extremely out-synced. Some parts of the video were suddenly sped up and the audio and scene was out-of-place, although length of the full video remained the same. I haven't yet tried turning the framerate to 30 as it wouldn't probably work, since the clips all have a varying framerate.

So what happened and what is the best way to fix this?

Comment: Did you enable "AV Sync" in the timeline while you were editing?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that. If I set it to No Sync some clips will be repeated which is also not my intention.

Comment: Pffff I need to learn how to read. Can you share a minimal example so we can check it out for ourselves?

Comment: May be of help? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NrX1sK_ZQqs&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4&index=27